# Could not open database file Windows Store App 8.1

Tags: windows-store-apps, sqlite-net

I'm trying to implement a database in my Windows 8.1 Modern UI application.
I made this for a Windows Phone 8.1 app successfully, but it doesn't work in a new Windows 8.1 app.

I got a `SQLiteException` with message `Could not open database file: MyAppBase.db (CannotOpen)` when i instanciate `SQLiteConnection`

```
public static DatabaseHelper Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new DatabaseHelper();
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public DatabaseHelper()
    {
        _connection = new SQLiteConnection(DATABASE_NAME);

        _connection.CreateTable<UserEntity>();
    }
```

I follow this steps :
Added 'sqlite-net' to Nuget reference, Checked 'SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1)' and 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Package for Windows' on project references, Targetted build to x86.

How can i get this working ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQLite needs a path to create a DB not just a db name

try something like this

```
string path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, DATABASE_NAME);

_connection = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ah. Of course, it has to go with the app. Thanks! For some dumb reason I thought I could use "C:\temp\" or another folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
string path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, databasePath);
```